# A statistical test for difference other than absolute Z-score >2

Tags: r, probability, distributions, statistical-significance, z-score

I'm afraid I'm going to show my statistical ignorance here. I am looking at the number of times a gene is identified in a network analysis. Or another way, I'm looking to see if there are a couple of genes that are over represented in all the pathways identified by my analysis.

The result of this is shown below, but to me there seems to be some clear genes that are constantly appearing. As I understand, it is OK to take a Z-score of the data and deem any absolute Z-scores >2 to be significantly different. People generally don't seem to like this method but I don't know of a better way (yet).

I would like to use the table of results (bottom of the page) to test which of these values are significantly different to the main distribution of the data.

By Eye and a distribution curve anything above 6 looks pretty over represented but I want to confirm that with statistics. (red line is the median)
[image]

Thank you in advance for any help, even if it's just the name of a test to look up and learn about :-).

Gene EntrezID and Frequency below (This is just the result of running the R command table() to work out the frequency of which each gene appears);

```
 5291   5293   5604    673   1956   5728   1870   5170   1027    355   9586   3326   3802   3804   3811   3812    476   4775    478   5321   6195   6196   6776   6789  92579   1906   2246  22849   3127   3315   3460   3805   3809   3939   4208   4214  51422   5211   5915    637   7867    843   8877    890  10059  10197 115653 117157 133522   1654   1783   2317  26052  27094  27436   2912   2917   2946   3291   3577   3600    361   3673   3689   4306   4881    490  56894  56895   5869   5871   5878   5993   7155   7417   7704    781   9455   9618    995    996 
22     22     19     12     11      9      7      7      6      6      6      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      3      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      2      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1      1
```

Comment: OK, so far I've understood that you have count data of your genes and want to identify genes with "unusual" high (significantly higher) counts. Correct? Are counts of different genes independent? Can we assume that the counts of each gene follow a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)? Your simplified Gauss test certainly doesn't seem appropriate for this kind of data.

Comment: Hi Roland, very sorry I was waiting for an e-mail alert on this and none came!

Comment: You are correct in your summary of what I'm wanting to identify. From that wiki it sounds like an assumption of a Poisson distribution is a fair one. The counts of different genes I believe are independent too.